# Do we need to remove listeners from a stream before assigning a new value to the variable holding the stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

Do we need to remove the listeners attached to a variable before we replace it by another one?

Here is a pseudo use case:

```
class Writer {
  constructor() {
    this.extention = 0;
    this.changeFile();
  }

  changeFile() {
    this.extention++;

    // Do we need to remove the listeners from the previous stream, or will nodeJS be able to do it automatically since the stream will be destroyed by the GC ?
    this.file = fs.createWriteStream('file-'+this;extention+'.txt');

    this.file.on('error', doSomething);
    this.file.on('drain', doSomething);
    this.file.on('finish', doSomething);
  }
}

var writer = new Writer();

setInterval(function() {
  // ...

  writer.changeFile();
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collector will remove the events along with the object, if you don't have a reference for that stream anywhere.

There is a nice [thread about this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/TbNDkeT9FkU).